# Perfect ring Vs perfect module

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

In the ring theory, a left perfect ring is a type of ring in which all left modules have projective covers. The right case is defined by analogy and a ring is perfect means it is both left and right perfect. You can see more at wiki [perfect ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

But in the commutative algebra, we have a similar concept perfect module. A R-module M is perfect, if proj dim(M)=grade(M). But I do not find the word perfect module here in the wiki.

Is any relationship between the perfect ring in the ring theory and the perfect module in the  commutative algebra?

Comment: What do you mean by "grade" of a module, here?

Comment: The definition of grade is that  proj dim(M)=grade(M) I have wrote，we can see it in this book p25: http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=LF6CbQk9uScC&printsec=frontcover&hl=zh-CN#v=onepage&q&f=false, some books also call it depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, there is a definition of "perfect module" that aligns with perfect rings is the one given [here](http://www.math.uni-duesseldorf.de/~wisbauer/book.pdf) in Wisbauer's text.

> We call $N$ *perfect* in $σ[M]$ if, for every index set $Λ$, the sum $N^{(Λ)}$ is semiperfect in $σ[M]$.

In the category of $R$ modules, that would be

> We call the $R$ module $N$ *perfect* if, for every index set $Λ$, the sum $N^{(Λ)}$ is a semiperfect $R$ module$.

I do not know if this relates to the commutative algebra definition, but on the surface it does not look like it. It could just be a case of divergence in terminology due to the choice of generic adjectives like *regular*, *normal*, *perfect* which show up a lot.

Comment: The perfect module is in the book Cohen-Macaulay Rings, p25, you can see it at here: http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=LF6CbQk9uScC&printsec=frontcover&hl=zh-CN#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @Strongart OK thanks for the reference. I don't understand anything in my first reading of it, and nothing reminds me of anything I've learned about perfect rings, so I still feel like the names are just a coincidence.

Comment: Maybe it is just a coincidence, but I am not sure.

Comment: @Strongart if you read the link I gave, maybe you will see.

Comment: The “prefect module" in your book follows the perfect ring, maybe it is really a coincidence.